# Prevent jQuery .clone() from disappearing after page changes/refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

This is my first question asked at StackOverflow, so, first of all, I want to thank everyone for such a huge knowledge database you've built here :)

I'm building a form that consists of 4 sections, each one of that sections with specific inputs on it. The form also has some other fields that are dynamically shown or hidden, based on your previous answers (for example, if you select "Yes" from a radio button which says "Is there anyone else who owns more than 5% of the business?", a new fieldset called 'partner_information' will pop up using .show(), with some specific information regarding partner attributes: First name, Last name, Email, and Percentage of business).

This fieldset also has an "add another partner" button, which clones the 'partner_attributes' fieldset and assigns a specific ID to the clones. The code for the cloning part is this:

```
var cloneCount = 2;
  $(document).on('click',
    ".userBackendAddAnotherPartnerCTALink",
      function () {
        $('[id^=partner-information]:last').clone().attr('id', 'partner-information-'+ cloneCount++).insertAfter($('[id^=partner-information]:last')).find("input").val("").attr("name",function(i,oldVal) {
          return oldVal.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(_,m){
            return "[" + (+m + 1) + "]";
        });
      });
    });
```

The issue comes when I change the section of the form or refresh the page: Since it's a very complex and long form, I want the user to be able to go forward and backwards within the form sections, complete the information they want in each one of them, and be able to come back after, and complete all the information before submitting the form.

Being that said, you can imagine that my main issue comes when a user clicks on "Add another partner", clones the partner_attributes fieldset, completes all the fields regarding partner attributes, and goes to another section: If they return to the partners section after changing the page, the cloned fieldset had disappeared, because the DOM had been refreshed.

The app is running in Rails 4, in case that information is useful for you. Below is the code for both the radio buttons that trigger the .show() and .hide() jQuery methods for the partner_attributes fieldset:

```
<!-- input more than 5% of the business -->
      <div class="userBackendAFInputContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <!-- label -->
        <label for="more-than-5" class="userBackendAFLabel">Is there anyone else who owns more than 5% of the business?</label>
        <!-- label -->

        <!-- yes -->
        <div class="userBackendAFRadioBtnContainer">

          <!-- input -->
          <input type="radio" name="loan_application[partners_attributes][]" value="yes" id="more-than-5-yes" class="userBackendAFRadioButtons" <%= 'checked' if @loan_application.partners.any? %> ><span></span>
          <!-- input -->

          <!-- label -->
          <label class="userBackendRadioButtonsTxt" for="more-than-5-yes">Yes</label>
          <!-- label -->

        </div>
        <!-- yes -->

        <!-- no -->
        <div class="userBackendAFRadioBtnContainer">

          <!-- input -->
          <input type="radio" name="loan_application[partners_attributes][]" value="no" id="more-than-5-no" class="userBackendAFRadioButtons" <%= 'checked' if @loan_application.partners.empty? %> ><span></span>
          <!-- input -->

          <!-- label -->
          <label class="userBackendRadioButtonsTxt" for="more-than-5-no">No</label>
          <!-- label -->

        </div>
        <!-- no -->

      </div>
      <!-- input more than 5% of the business -->

      <!-- clear -->
      <div class="clearFix">&nbsp;</div>
      <!-- clear -->
```

And here, the fieldset to be cloned:

```
<!-- fieldset partner information -->
    <fieldset class="userBackendAFFormFieldset userBackendPartnerInformation" id="partner-information">

      <!-- title partner information -->
      <h5 class="userBackendAFFieldsetTitle col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">partner information</h5>
      <!-- title partner information -->

      <!-- clearfix -->
      <div class="clearFix">&nbsp;</div>
      <!-- clearfix -->

      <!-- input partner first name -->
      <div class="userBackendAFInputContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <!-- label -->
        <label for="partner-first-name" class="userBackendAFLabel">First Name</label>
        <!-- label -->

        <!-- input -->
        <input type="text" class="userBackendAFInput" id="partner-first-name"
          name="loan_application[partners_attributes][1][partner_first_name]" placeholder="Charles"
          value="<%= @loan_application.partners['1'].try(:[], 'partner_first_name') %>" />
        <!-- input -->

      </div>
      <!-- input partner first name -->

      <!-- input partner last name -->
      <div class="userBackendAFInputContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <!-- label -->
        <label for="partner-last-name" class="userBackendAFLabel">Last Name</label>
        <!-- label -->

        <!-- input -->
        <input type="text" class="userBackendAFInput" id="partner-last-name"
          name="loan_application[partners_attributes][1][partner_last_name]" placeholder="Estrada"
          value="<%= @loan_application.partners['1'].try(:[], 'partner_last_name') %>" />
        <!-- input -->

      </div>
      <!-- input partner last name -->

      <!-- clear -->
      <div class="clearFix">&nbsp;</div>
      <!-- clear -->

      <!-- input partner email -->
      <div class="userBackendAFInputContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <!-- label -->
        <label for="partner-email" class="userBackendAFLabel">Email</label>
        <!-- label -->

        <!-- input -->
        <input type="email" class="userBackendAFInput" id="partner-email"
          name="loan_application[partners_attributes][1][partner_email]" placeholder="oberbrunner_dianna@leffler.net"
          data-parsley-trigger="change" value="<%= @loan_application.partners['1'].try(:[], 'partner_email') %>" />
        <!-- input -->

      </div>
      <!-- input partner email -->

      <!-- input partner percentage of business container -->
      <div class="userBackendAFInputContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <!-- label -->
        <label for="partner-percentage-business" class="userBackendAFLabel">Percentage of the business</label>
        <!-- label -->

        <!-- input -->
        <input type="text" class="userBackendAFInput" id="partner-percentage-business"
          name="loan_application[partners_attributes][1][partner_percentage]" placeholder="%100"
          data-parsley-type="number" value="<%= @loan_application.partners['1'].try(:[], 'partner_percentage') %>" />
        <!-- input -->

      </div>
      <!-- input partner percentage of business container -->

      <!-- clearfix -->
      <div class="clearFix">&nbsp;</div>
      <!-- clearfix -->

    </fieldset>
    <!-- fieldset partner information -->

    <!-- add another partner cta -->
    <div class="userBackendAddAnotherPartnerCTA">
      <span class="userBackendAddAnotherPartnerCTALink">+ add another partner</span>
    </div>
    <!-- add another partner cta -->
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Let me know if you need more information in order to solve this.

Comment: you're not going to be able to persist the cloned elements this way, since these elements are being added to the DOM dynamically they are always going to wipe on refresh. You're best bet is to look into persisting data with rails into a model then loading the form data and building out the form on pageload depending on whether or not the given session has saved data.

Comment: I see, that sounds reasonable. Thanks a lot, will give that a try!

Comment: added comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

you're not going to be able to persist the cloned elements this way, since these elements are being added to the DOM dynamically they are always going to wipe on refresh. You're best bet is to look into persisting data with rails into a model then loading the form data and building out the form on pageload depending on whether or not the given session has saved data.